# How to hide a process for user in autoit

Tags: autoit

Hello i try to hide this process for the user in autoit but i don't know how, if someone can help me !

RunWait('wscript.exe "OffScrub03.vbs" ALL /Quiet /NoCancel')

Thanks in advance.

Comment: when i say hide it's the windows, not the process in taskmanager.

Answer (score 1):

In order to run a application with hidden GUI you should use
**@SW_HIDE** as a third parameter in your Run, RunWait call.